# how to plot negative numbers from small to large value using geom_bar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to be able to plot a bar chart from left to right using only negative values.  The low value is on the left with the bar length reaching to the single observed value.  If I need to give a starting minimum value, I can do that, say -105 in the  example I provide below.

for some reason I am not able to use xlim or ylim to control the scale

```
a <- as.factor(c("x","y","z"))
b <- c(-105, -87, -99)
neg_tib <- tibble(a,b)

neg_plot <- ggplot(neg_tib, aes(x = a, y = b))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "identity", 
           color = "blue", fill = "transparent", 
           width = .1) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-80, -100)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_tufte()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scale_y_reverse()` instead of `scale_y_continuous()` to reverse your axis and get something that reverses the bars.  I also added breaks every -20 units to make it look a bit more complete:

```
neg_plot <- ggplot(neg_tib, aes(x = a, y = b))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "identity", 
           color = "blue", fill = "transparent", 
           width = .1) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(0,-100, by=-20)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_tufte()
```

[image]

Setting axis limits on bar plots is heavily discouraged, as it is convention that bars "start" at 0.  If you are looking to show where you set limits on the axis, I would suggest using another geom (points, lines, etc... depends on your data).

Nevertheless, if you *absolutely must* "zoom in" on the edges of bars, you can set the limits within `coord_flip()`.  Why there?  You can set limits in `scale_y_reverse(limits=c(...))`; however, just like other `scale_*` functions, the limits within these functions and via `xlim()` and `ylim()` end up zooming in on your data *and removing any datapoints outside those limits*.  This is not always a problem, but for the `bar` and `col` geoms, for example, these actually *start* at 0 and extend to whatever the `y` aesthetic would be.  So for the bar that ends at -105, the geom extends from 0 to -105.  This means when you zoom in with `limits=` inside of `scale_y_reverse()` or `ylim()`, it will zoom the axis, but it will no longer plot those geoms (because they extend outside those limits).

To zoom in but keep all geoms regardless of whether or not they extend outside the limits set, you can set those limits inside any `coord_*` function.  That includes `coord_cartesian()`, or in your case, `coord_flip()`.  Here's what it looks like zoomed in.  I've also set the `breaks` on your `y` axis to be smaller to accomodate the different zoom:

```
neg_plot <- ggplot(neg_tib, aes(x = a, y = b))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "identity", 
           color = "blue", fill = "transparent", 
           width = .1) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(0,-100, by=-20)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_tufte()
```

[image]

Once again, I have to emphasize **it is really bad practice to show bar graphs this way**.  The reason is that in the plot above it looks like `z` is about double the value of `y`, while in reality the value of `z` is -99 and the value of `y` is -87.  *Definitely* not double that of `y`, unless you "start" at -80.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this still has the bar starting from 0.  I wish for the beginning of the bar value to be the low value, perhaps fixed like -105 or even min(b).  Also the left side of x axis should still start the lower value, with a smaller, negative value being larger.

Comment: I've added the way to set limits to your plot to the answer.

Comment: I thank you for investing time in my problem.  Yes, I agree it is against good practice, and for myself I would do this differently, but I have a customer who wishes to see it this way.  I think maybe if I could define the base as -105 and have that start on the left, then the bar reaches to the right with appropriate scale below,

Comment: That could work, yes.  Sorry - have to make that PSA even if you understand.  :)